# How to get rid of car paint smell after workshop repair

Tags: body-work

I have a quite tricky question. Recently i got two doors of my car painted at the workshop (professionally done). The problem is that it has been a couple of days now, and i cannot get rid of the paint smell inside the car. Any suggestions? Making the situation worst is the fact that i don't have a garage and it's already winter --so assume very little daylight and cold humid air (-5 Celsius and >60% humidity).

I am trying to ventilate the interior of the car as much as possible but it doesn't really help :(

Best Regards,
Konstantinos.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did you try active carbon? Cars usually have that stuff to remove smell from gases coming out of the head cap, and those from gas tank ventilation.

Comment: Don't know if it will work for car paint, but we used to remove the smell of house paint by leaving a cut orange in the room overnight. (don't eat the orange afterwards - throw it away!)

Answer (score 0):

If they painted the inside surfaces of the door, then even though it is dry it is going to evaporate the voc’s volatile organic compounds... basically allow air movement ie ventilation and time...

Answer (score 0):

Rent a commercial ionizer and let it run inside of your vehicle for a 24 to 36 hours. Vacuum the interior thoroughly after.

A more "organic" way would be to buy a large bag of potatoes, spread them around and let it sit for a few days. Throw the potatoes away afterwards.